# How can I translate those translatable texts defined in t() in contribute/custom modules?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I wrote some custom modules, follow the Drupal standards, put all interface texts in t() function, make them translatable. Module enabled.

I enabled Locale module, added new Language under `admin/config/regional/language`:
[image]

However, under `admin/config/regional/translate/translate`
I cannot see those text I defined t('xxx') in my custom modules. (cache cleared)

How can I make Drupal aware of them? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [Translation template extractor module](http://drupal.org/project/potx) to extract all the `t()` calls you've done.

Another option is to get the `t()`processed, by viewing the pages where they are defined and then translate them in the interface you mention. (New strings will only be added once they have appeared once).

Comment: Thanks for this. I get a .pot file from web extract, how can I utilize it?

Comment: @gilzero Translate it and rename it to `.po`

Comment: Even if this module has no 8.x version yet, you can still use it to extract strings from a D8 module. See this thread : https://www.drupal.org/node/2356469